# how to use 50 thousand Ids at where or join clause in oracle pl/sql for a select query?

Tags: oracle, performance, join, plsql, temp-tables

I have a list of 50 thousand receipt Ids (hard coded values). i want to apply these 50 thousand Ids in where condition or join operation. I have used below 'with' clause to create a temp table to collect those 50 thousand Ids. Then I used this temp table in join query for filtering.

```
with temp_receiptIds(receiptId)
as
(
select 'M0000001' from dual
union
select 'M0000002' from dual
union
select 'M0000003' from dual
union
select 'M0000004' from dual
..
..
...
union
select 'M0049999' from dual
union
select 'M0050000' from dual
)

select sal.receiptId, prd.product_name, prd.product_price, sal.sales_date, sal.seller_name 
from product prd 
join sales sal on prd.product_id=sal.product_id 
join temp_receiptIds tmp on tmp.receiptId=sal.receiptId
```

Whenever I run the above select join query to extract data as requested by business people, it takes about 8 minutes to fetch result in the production server.
Is my above approach correct? Are there any simpler approach than this by considering best performance in the production server.
Please note, every second , the production database is used by customer. since production db is very busy, can I run this query in production db directly, will it cause slow performance in the customer using website which calls this production db in every second. Correct answers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: 50,000 hard-coded values?!?!  Where do they originate?  How do the come to you that you hard-code them into 50,000 individual SELECT statements?  Surely you could use a utility to load them into a table and reference them from there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @thatjeffsmith. 50,000 hard-coded values are originated from a csv file.

Comment: Did I reply? Put those csv's into a table and this becomes as easy as a where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you store those `receiptID`s into a table?

```
create table receiptids as
with temp_receiptIds(receiptId)
as
(
select 'M0000001' from dual
union all                        --> "union ALL" instead of "union"
...
) 
select * from temp_receiptids;
```

Index it:

```
create index i1recid on receiptids (receiptIdD);
```

See how that query now behaves.

---

If you - for some reason - can't do that, see whether `UNION ALL` within the CTE does any good. For 50.000 rows, it could make a difference.

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot for the reply :), Yes you are correct!, 'Union all' improves the performance better than 'union'.
And regarding creating temp table, I have read-only permission to fetch production data. In this case, is it possible to use index for the best performance? 
Thank you Pal in advance :)

Comment: As you suggested, I used 'create table..' but it throws below error,
ORA-04031: unable to allocate 127448 bytes of shared memory ("shared pool","create table receiptids as
w...","SQLA^2cf9d958","qsmksol : qsmg_alloc_sol")
Please advise how to overcome this, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you have read-only access, there's nothing much you can do about creating tables. See if DBA can create it for you - perhaps in another schema, and let you access it. As of ORA-04031, it usually means that you (i.e. the DBA) should add more RAM to SGA.

Comment: Sounds like you and your DBA need a serious conversation. First, as @Littlefoot suggests they need to take a serious look system configuration, 50K rows is actually relatively small. Second have them create an application role that has write access and GRANT  you to that role. You need then to look into SQL LOADER to load the csv.  Loading this data, meaning *writing it*, is part of your job; the job of the DBA is to ensure you have every thing necessary to accomplish yours. Keep in mind you and the DBA are both part of the same team, at least as far as the rest the organization is concerned.

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot and Belayer :). I accept your suggestions. I will check with our DBA.

Comment: I hope this question and answers are very useful and clear. Myself and beneficiary people appreciate all of you for your Great Contribution for finding this solution to the above problem. Thanks & Cheers! :-)